# Network scan failed

Tags: networking, python-2.7

I try to scan available port on my network at home. But I got a few problem and error. Can someone tell me what the matter is going on to my script

**Here is my script**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import socket, sys
from optparse import OptionParser 

def scan_server(address, port): 
s = socket.socket() 
 print "Attempting to connect to %s on port %s." %(address, port) 
 try: 
     s.connect((address, port)) 
     print "Connected to server %s on port %s." %(address, port) 
     return True 
 except socket.error, e: 
     print "Connecting to %s on port %s failed with the following error: %s" %(address, 
     port, e) 
     return False

if __name__ == '__main__': 
 parser = OptionParser() 
 parser.add_option("-a", "--address", dest="address", default="localhost",      
 parser.add_option("-p", "--port", dest="port", help="PORT for server", metavar="PORT") 
 (options, args) = parser.parse_args() 
 if options.port == 'all': 
     print 'checking all ports...' 
 for x in range(1,65536): 
     print 'checking port %s on %s' %(x, options.address) 
     check = scan_server(options.address, x) 
     print 'scan_server returned %s' %(check) 
 else: 
     options.port = int(options.port) 
     print 'options: %s, args: %s' %(options, args) 
     check = scan_server(options.address, options.port) 
     print 'scan_server returned %s' %(check) 
     Ssys.exit(not check)
```

**And here is my error**

checking port 1 on localhost
Attempting to connect to localhost on port 1.
Connecting to localhost on port 1 failed with the following error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
scan_server returned False
checking port 2 on localhost

Attempting to connect to localhost on port 2.
Connecting to localhost on port 2 failed with the following error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
scan_server returned False
checking port 3 on localhost

Attempting to connect to localhost on port 3.
Connecting to localhost on port 3 failed with the following error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
scan_server returned False
checking port 4 on localhost

Attempting to connect to localhost on port 4.
Connecting to localhost on port 4 failed with the following error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
scan_server returned False
checking port 5 on localhost

Attempting to connect to localhost on port 5.
Connecting to localhost on port 5 failed with the following error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
scan_server returned False
checking port 6 on localhost

Attempting to connect to localhost on port 6.

Answer (score 5):

There's no error. Your local machine (the one you are scanning) doesn't have anything listening on those ports, so the connection is being refused.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'available ports'. The operating system will refuse connections on any port which does not have something *bound* to it. On Linux-like operating systems there is a system call named `bind` which registers a program as intending to listen on that port. The vast majority of ports on your machine will be 'available' in that nothing is bound to them.

Here's [a reference of commonly used ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).

Comment: I'm sorry for mistake. I mean by the failure of the attempting to connect. Actually i'm trying to find out the protocol runing on every host that connect to my network. I found a script to search port for localhost. But i didnt know how to get all the other port 
of host. 

http://codepad.org/HpzcVyet

this is my script for scanning port on my localhost

Comment: I explained why you're getting that failure in my answer. However, if that's what you're trying to do, just use [nmap](http://nmap.org) rather than trying to write it yourself.